# Criando um Entry formatado para CPF em Python (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Gostaria de saber como seria a aplicação de uma formatação em um campo `Entry`, utilizando o `tkinter`, para o formato de números de CPF, no caso, `XXX.XXX.XXX-XX`. Não achei nada parecido, encontrando apenas soluções na linguagem Java ou JavaScript.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para formatar o CPF enquanto o usuário o digita, basta criar uma função para tratar a string e atribuir um evento para o objeto `entry`, para executar a função a cada tecla apertada — utilizando o método `entry.bind`, passando como argumento o evento e a função de formatação.

Na função para formatar a string, você deve obter o texto do widgtet — utilizando o método `get` — e depois verificar se a tecla apertada foi um `"BackSpace"`. Dessa forma, a função só formatará a string caso mais um caractere tenha sido acrescentado ao texto. Isso evita que a função "trave" o texto quando o usuário quiser apagar algum caractere. É importante salientar que a função deve ter em sua assinatura um parâmetro para receber o evento.

```
def format_cpf(event = None):
    
    # Obtém o texto, removendo todos os sinais e mantendo apenas os números, 
    # além de estabelecer um limite de 11 caracteres à string.
    text = entry.get().replace(".", "").replace("-", "")[:11]
    new_text = ""

    if event.keysym.lower() == "backspace": return
```

Após isso, percorra todos os caracteres do texto, verificando se todos eles são números. É importante ressaltar que utilizar o método `isnumeric` ou `isdigit`, como [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/492728/157404), não é recomendado nesse caso, pois existem muitos caracteres *Unicode* que são validados pelo método. Clique [aqui](https://ideone.com/K4R1Fd) para saber quais caracteres são validados ou não pelos métodos.

Para fazer a validação, verifique se o caractere está dentro de uma string contendo apenas números, de zero a nove. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
if char in "0123456789":
    # Código...
```

Depois de ter verificado se o caractere é um valor numérico, adicione-o para uma nova string, junto com os sinais de ponto e traço — verificando o índice do mesmo.

Supondo que o CPF seja `"92187321245"` (CPF aleatório), você deve adicionar um ponto após o 3º e o 6º dígito, e um traço após o 9º dígito, para que o CPF fique assim: `"921.873.212-45"`. Dessa forma, você deve verificar os caracteres nos índices 2, 5 e 8, como no código abaixo:

```
if index in [2, 5]: new_text += text[index] + "."  # Índice 2 ou 5 -> Ponto
elif index == 8: new_text += text[index] + "-"     # índice 8 -> Traço
else: new_text += text[index]                      # Outros -> Nenhum sinal
```

Para aplicar a formatação, você deve apagar todo o texto da `entry` e adicionar a nova string, formatada, ao widget — utilizando os método `delete` e `insert` — como no código abaixo:

```
entry.delete(0, "end")
entry.insert(0, new_text)
```

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
def format_cpf(event = None):
    
    text = entry.get().replace(".", "").replace("-", "")[:11]
    new_text = ""

    if event.keysym.lower() == "backspace": return
    
    for index in range(len(text)):
        
        if not text[index] in "0123456789": continue
        if index in [2, 5]: new_text += text[index] + "."
        elif index == 8: new_text += text[index] + "-"
        else: new_text += text[index]

    entry.delete(0, "end")
    entry.insert(0, new_text)


from tkinter import *
screen = Tk()

entry = Entry(screen, font = ("Arial", 20))
entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", format_cpf)
entry.pack()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adaptei o programa [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242970/tkinter-entry-box-formatted-for-date/13243973) e funcionou bem.

**Nota 1** Imaginando este CPF 11.111.111-11 - O mesmo teria que ser entrado como 011.111.111-11

**Nota 2** Deve ser dado ENTER para que o campo seja "lido"

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


class CpfEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, frame_look={}, **look):
        args = dict(relief=tk.SUNKEN, border=1)
        args.update(frame_look)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **args)

        args = {'relief': tk.FLAT}
        args.update(look)

        self.entry_1 = tk.Entry(self, width=3, **args)
        self.label_1 = tk.Label(self, text='.', **args)
        self.entry_2 = tk.Entry(self, width=3, **args)
        self.label_2 = tk.Label(self, text='.', **args)
        self.entry_3 = tk.Entry(self, width=3, **args)
        self.label_3 = tk.Label(self, text='-', **args)
        self.entry_4 = tk.Entry(self, width=2, **args)

        self.entry_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.label_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.entry_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.label_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.entry_3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.label_3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.entry_4.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.entries = [self.entry_1, self.entry_2, self.entry_3, self.entry_4]

        self.entry_1.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: self._check(0, 3))
        self.entry_2.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: self._check(1, 3))
        self.entry_3.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: self._check(2, 3))
        self.entry_4.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: self._check(3, 2))

    def _backspace(self, entry):
        cont = entry.get()
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, cont[:-1])

    def _check(self, index, size):
        entry = self.entries[index]
        next_index = index + 1
        next_entry = self.entries[next_index] if next_index < len(self.entries) else None
        data = entry.get()

        if len(data) > size or not data.isdigit():
            self._backspace(entry)
        if len(data) >= size and next_entry:
            next_entry.focus()

    def get(self):
        return [e.get() for e in self.entries]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title('CPF - demo')

    cpf_entry = CpfEntry(win, font=('Arial', 40, tk.NORMAL), border=0)
    cpf_entry.pack()

    win.bind('<Return>', lambda e: print(cpf_entry.get()))
    win.mainloop()
```

Espero que ajude